# End of support for Gazebo in 2025

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using Gazebo in my job. Basically I try to build a virtual copy of our robot and add functionalities to Gazebo we need to get a precise simulation of our use cases. And my boss is now asking the question what happens to our project after 2025. I was searching but couldn't construct a coherent answer.

Would it be possible to not change anything and continue developing on Gazebo-7? What would be the drawbacks? Would it be possible to use the Ignition Gazebo instead? How difficult it would be? Are there other alternatives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24198/end-of-support-for-gazebo-in-2025/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The simulation team at Open Robotics is currently working on the release of Gazebo 11, which is planned to be the last version released from the [osrf/gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo) codebase. Gazebo 11 will EOL in 2025.

The team is also working on the next generation of Gazebo, called [Ignition](https://blog.openrobotics.org/acropolis/). Ignition has already had 2 named releases (`acropolis` and `blueprint`) and the next one, codenamed `citadel` is coming up next week.

> Would it be possible to not change anything and continue developing on Gazebo-7? What would be the drawbacks?

It's possible, but Gazebo 7's EOL is on 2021 and after that we won't be making patch releases or porting it to newer platforms. It's highly recommended you upgrade to a supported version, either Gazebo's or Ignition's, on 2021.

> Would it be possible to use the Ignition Gazebo instead? How difficult it would be?

Citadel will be Ignition’s first 5-year LTS, but we still expect large changes in the upcoming versions, as the codebase is currently under fast-paced development. If you need features which are in Ignition but not on Gazebo, you're welcome to try it out. The migration from Gazebo to Ignition is currently not very straightforward and we plan on improving that in the coming months.

> Are there other alternatives?

Staying within the Open Robotics simulation realm, I recommend you upgrade from Gazebo 7 to Gazebo 11 once that's released, and eventually move to Ignition before 2025. There are also other simulators out there.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-04-11**:
What is the reason you recommend to move to Gazebo 11 and not Gazebo 9 before migrating to Ignition?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-13**:
Gazebo 11 is the latest LTS, and it also shares the same Ignition / SDFormat dependencies as Ignition Citadel.